# Move EditText From Top to Under Other EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a 3 CheckBox and 3 EditText and when i check corresponding checkbox that EditText should Move bottom of other Two EditText. I searched on Internet but Unable to Find anything about it Need Some Advice or Sample Code Thank You in Advance

Sample Xml Code Actual Layout Structure:

```
<RelativeLayout>
              <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chk1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Task 1"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout id="Linear2">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/ch2" .../>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/et2" .../>
    <Image android:id="@+id/img2" .../>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout id="Linear3">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/ch3" .../>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/et3" .../>
    <Image android:id="@+id/img3" .../>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the code that you used so we can assist you ?

Comment: @Gastón Saillén added Xml Code..Thank you for Reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View android:id="@+id/v1" .../>
    <View android:id="@+id/v2" .../>
    <View android:id="@+id/v3" .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you need to do this in java in order to move v1 to the bottom:

```
LinearLayout container = findViewById(R.id.container);
View v1,v2,v3;
v1 = findViewById(R.id.v1);
v2 = findViewById(R.id.v2);
v3 = findViewById(R.id.v3);

View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    void onClick(View v) {
        container.removeView(v);
        container.addView(v);
    }
}

v1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
v2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
v3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Comment: @Rakesh it's about editing the `LayoutParams` for the linearlayout that you need to bot in the bottom.